# magento 2.3.4 update

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I have a webshop magento 2.3.4 https://www.agoshop.at and want ask if it make sense to update the magento shop to 2.4
When it make sense can somebody help me how I can do this update?
kindly regards for any help an answer how I can do this

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to the below link for the Magento upgrade

https://magecomp.com/blog/upgrade-magento-version-from-2-3-to-2-4/

Here Step to Upgrade

**Step 1:** Put your store in Maintenance Mode, so customers can’t interfere

```
bin/magento maintenance:enable
```

**Step 2:** Backup your Store/Server/Database via your preferred method

```
cp composer.json composer.json.bak
```

**Step 3:** Run the composer command to fetch the latest version (2.4.2)

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.2 --no-update
```

**Step 4:** Run the composer update (this will also fetch any available 3rd party modules where updates are available

```
composer update
```

**Step 5:** Clean the Magento Cache

```
bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Step 6:** Manually clear generated content

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* generated/code/*
```

**Step 7:** Update Magento Database and Schema

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

**Step 8:** Recompile Magento Code (If in Production Mode)

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

**Step 9:** Deploy Static Content (replace en_US with your locale reference)

```
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -f
```

**Step 10:** Clean the Magento Cache (I always run this immediately after a Static Deploy command)

bin/magento cache:clean

**Step 11:** Disable Maintenance Mode, so customers can visit the site

```
bin/magento maintenance:disable
```

Answer (score 0):

The  primary question here is if it "makes sense" to upgrade one major release to another, in this case from 2.3.x to 2.4.x.

It is always best practice to keep your Magento software up to date. The latest release fixes bugs and closes security holes. However, new releases introduce new features, some new features will break your existing shop especially if your frontend theme is also not up to date.

Before you look at the technical procedure to upgrade from one version to another read the [release notes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html) for the latest version to see exactly what the requirements are and whether your existing shop and server supports them.

For example Magento 2.4 no longer supports catalog search via the MySQL database

```
You must install and configure Elasticsearch before upgrading to Magento 2.4. x.
```

Are you able to install Elasticsearch on your server? Will you need to contact your server provider?

**You should never blindly perform an update on your live shop without first testing the update on your development / staging servers. Doing so will very likely break your shop and cost you money.**

- Do your own research first, make yourself aware of the changes your
  shop will have when you upgrade.
- Test everything thoroughly on a local copy of your shop.
- Make notes as you go through the upgrade so that you know what issues you have and how to fix them.
- Only after thoroughly testing the upgrade and your shop functionality with the new version start your plan to upgrade your live shop.
- Make sure you have a backup of your live shop before you start!

By following your upgrade plan you will have confidence that your upgrade will be successful.

To finally answer the original question, does it make sense to upgrade? Only you can answer that by researching the upgrade and comparing the pros and cons of what the new release will give your shop and your business.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for your answers.
I will try to make a copy of my existing shop and then I will try there a backup.
Please let me know how I can do best a copy of my existing shop.
kindly regards.